# Compare previous and next different values in a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column of floats that looks like this (the example is with integers for simplicity):

```
  col1                    
0 10    
1 10  
2 5
3 5
4 5
5 10
6 4
7 4
8 4
9 4
10 4
11 5
12 5
```

I am trying to create a new column that compares, for each row, the previous and next *different* values that the one in that row and assigns a boolean according if they are equal or not. For example, in row[2], the value is 5, the previous *different* value (not 5) is 10 in row[1] and the next *different* value is 10 in row[5]. In this case, the value in the new column would be `True`.

Then, for the example df the output I am trying to get is

```
  col1  col2                
0 10    NaN
1 10    False
2 5     True
3 5     True
4 5     True
5 10    False
6 4     False
7 4     False
8 4     False
9 4     False
10 4    False
11 5    False
12 5    NaN
```

I know how to do the comparison with a specific number of previous and following rows, but I don't know if it's possible to do the comparison searching for the "first different value".

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why would index `1` and `11` be False while `0` and `12` be `NaN`? There's no previous/next *different* value for those as well.

Comment: In this case, the value in index `1` is 10, the previous is 10 and the next is 5, that's why it would be a False. Same for index `11`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with unique value in a row and then `reindex` like:

```
s = df['col1'] #to ease the code
#where the value is not the same as before
m = s.diff().ne(0) 
# unique value if following
su = s[m].reset_index(drop=True)
print (su)
# 0    10
# 1     5
# 2    10
# 3     4
# 4     5
# Name: col1, dtype: int64

#create columns in df to align previous and after not equal value
df['col1_after'] = su.reindex(m.cumsum().values).values
df['col1_before'] = su.reindex(m.cumsum().values-2).values
#create col2 where the two previous columns are equal
df['col2'] = df['col1_after'].eq(df['col1_before'])
```

and you get

```
print (df)
    col1  col1_after  col1_before   col2
0     10         5.0          NaN  False
1     10         5.0          NaN  False
2      5        10.0         10.0   True
3      5        10.0         10.0   True
4      5        10.0         10.0   True
5     10         4.0          5.0  False
6      4         5.0         10.0  False
7      4         5.0         10.0  False
8      4         5.0         10.0  False
9      4         5.0         10.0  False
10     4         5.0         10.0  False
11     5         NaN          4.0  False
12     5         NaN          4.0  False
```

Note you can do `df.drop(['col1_after','col1_before'], axis=1)` to remove not necessary columns, I left them here to show what is happening

Comment: Thank you very much!